# I am receiving an error when deploying to vercel with react

Tags: html, reactjs, vercel

Everything was fine this morning then now receiving this error. Any ideas, i'm using create-react-app

[image: No error in vscode]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a `!` somewhere causing an error

Comment: That's what I figured but how will I located this !

Comment: If you are in vscode, press `Ctrl+Shift+F` to search all files. If you are using git and everything was fine this morning, you may be able to find the `!` by looking at recent commits also

Comment: Yup just tried that, no error with that !. This is so odd.

Comment: Now it's saying a have a random "/" somewhere